# Parameter upcasting in Drupal 8 with Form Controller

Tags: 8, routes

I have created a custom module with `mymodule.routing.yml` in which I am using own parameter `{my_menu}`. I have created a `mymodule.services.yml` file too in which I have used class for `param conversion`. Parameter conversion class is calling properly but I am not able to get the parameter in `Form Controller` class.

Code that I have written :

**mymoudle.routing.yml :**

```
entity.my_menu.mymodule:
  path: '/node/{my_menu}/mytab'
  defaults:
    _title: 'My Title'
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyModuleformControllerForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'edit my page'
    _entity_access: 'my_menu.update'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      my_menu:
        type: my_menu
```

**mymoudle.services.yml :**

```
services:
  my_menu:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\ParamConverter\MyModuleParamConverter
    tags:
      - { name: paramconverter }
```

**src/ParamConverter/MyModuleParamConverter.php :**

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function convert($value, $definition, $name, array $defaults) {
  dsm($value); // Node id that exists.
  return Node::load($value);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function applies($definition, $name, Route $route) {
  return (!empty($definition['type']) && $definition['type'] == 'my_menu');
}
```

**src/Controller/MyModuleformControllerForm :**

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, NodeInterface $node = NULL) {
  dsm($node); // It is null here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable needs to be called my_menu, check ControllerResolver